# How to open new tab without losing referer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, browser

My purpose is open new tab without losing referer. So, I have this code:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
});
```

It worked like a charm but it doesn't keep referer when I use IE browser. I search and see below code but I don't how to apply to my problem.

```
<form action="http://google.com" method="get" name="redirect"></form>
<script> document.forms['redirect'].submit() </script>
```

So, there is any way which work for all browser ?

Comment: Could you add a url parameter to be your referer?  referer are usually considered suspect anyway

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand what you said @TobyAllen

Comment: why do you need to keep the referer?  could you just open a page with www.mywebsite.com?referer=myotherwebsite.com and then read that in your new page.

Comment: @TobyAllen, Hi I cannot do that

Comment: what happens if you submit a form `<form action='http://google.com' target=_blank ><input type=submit></form>`?

Comment: @TobyAllen , google_analytics needs it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="q" onkeypress="doit(event,this.value)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doit(e,value){
if (e.which == 13){//or e.keyCode
     window.open('http://www.google.com/?#q='+value, '_blank');
  }
}
</script>
```

edit: you don't need form just use input and javascript function to check if user hits enter then open the new page with value which user types.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

When linking from one document to another in Internet Explorer 4.0 and later, the Referer header will not be sent when the link is from an HTTPS page to a non-HTTPS page. The Referer header also will not be sent when the link is from a non-HTTP(S) protocol, such as file://, to another page.
for more info go to this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178066)